# Get the text of an element using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I am having some trouble getting the text of elements using `querySelectorAll`. I already tried using `querySelector` but it only gives me the value of the first element. What I want to achieve is to get the text of the clicked element. Here's my code:

```
function __(selector){

   var self = {};
   self.selector = selector;

   if(typeof selector == 'undefined'){
      self.element = [self.selector];
   }else{
      self.element = document.querySelectorAll(self.selector);
   }

   // creating a method (.on)

    self.on = function(type, callback){
        self.element.forEach(function(elements){
           elements['on' + type] = callback;
        });
    }

     self.text = function(elems){
          [].slice.call(self.element).forEach(function(el,i){
                return el.innerHTML;
           });
     }

     return self;
}
```

And the HTML File:

```
<script src="selector.js"></script>
<script>
   window.onload = function(){

        __('p').on('click', function(){
               alert(__(this).text());
        });
   }
</script>

<p>Hello</p>  
<p>World</p>
```

The code above gives me an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually throws an error: `SyntaxError: '[object HTMLElement]' is not a valid selector`. This is because at `__(this)` you’re passing the selected element itself to the function, not a selector. You could account for this by including this as a third case:

```
if(typeof selector == "undefined"){
  self.element = [self.selector];
}
else if(typeof selector == "string"){
  self.element = document.querySelectorAll(self.selector);
}
else if(selector instanceof HTMLElement){
  self.element = [selector];
}
```

Now, the actual problem you’ve described occurs because you [don’t return anything in the `self.text` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7209794/4642212). The `return` is for the `forEach` function argument, which is ignored. Return the texts in the `self.text` function itself and use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `forEach`. Something like this:

```
self.text = function(elems){
  return [].slice.call(self.element).map(function(el,i){
    return el.innerHTML;
  });
}
```

This will return an array with the inner HTML texts for each element.

### Code in action

```js
function __(selector) {

  var self = {};
  self.selector = selector;

  if (typeof selector == "undefined") {
    self.element = [self.selector];
  } else if (typeof selector == "string") {
    self.element = document.querySelectorAll(self.selector);
  } else if (selector instanceof HTMLElement) {
    self.element = [selector];
  }

  // creating a method (.on)

  self.on = function(type, callback) {
    self.element.forEach(function(elements) {
      elements['on' + type] = callback;
    });
  }

  self.text = function(elems) {
    return [].slice.call(self.element).map(function(el, i) {
      return el.innerHTML;
    });
  }

  return self;
}

console.log(__("p").text()); // Logs texts of all <p>s

__("p").on("click", function() {
  console.log(__(this).text()); // Logs text of clicked <p>
});
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>World</p>
```