# .find(predicate) returns array instead of boolean

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing many writing systems:

```
var SCRIPTS = [
  {
    name: "Adlam",
    ranges: [[125184, 125259], [125264, 125274], [125278, 125280]],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 1987,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fula_alphabets#Adlam_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Han",
    ranges: [[11904, 11930], [11931, 12020], [12032, 12246], [12293, 12294], [12295, 12296], [12321, 12330], [12344, 12348], [13312, 19894], [19968, 40939], [63744, 64110], [64112, 64218], [131072, 173783], [173824, 177973], [177984, 178206], [178208, 183970], [183984, 191457], [194560, 195102]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: -1100,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters"
  },
  // and many more entries
}
```

My task is to figure out to which writing system a character belongs:

```
scriptOfSample("英", SCRIPTS) // han
```

Here's my first appraoch, which is a working solution.

```
function scriptOfSample(a, scripts) {
    const codePoint = a.codePointAt(0)
    for (let language of scripts) {
        let isInRange = language.ranges.find(([from, to]) => from <= codePoint && codePoint <= to)
        if (isInRange) {
            return language.name
        }
    }

    return undefined
}
```

Out of curiosity I've tried to use an approach with the `.forEach()` method.

```
function scriptOfSample(a, scripts) {
    const codePoint = a.codePointAt(0)
    scripts.forEach(({ranges, name}) => {
        let isInRange = ranges.find(([from, to]) => from <= codePoint && codePoint <= to)
        if (Array.isArray(isInRange)) {
            console.log("found one")
            return name
        }
    })

    return undefined
}
```

However, in this case `isInRange` isn't a boolean value but contains the range `[from, to]` in which the predicate was true.

What I'd like to know:

1. Why is the `find()` method returning different values?
2. What can I do (How do I have to adjust my implementation), to check if value "is in range"?

Comment: [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) always returns an item from the array or `undefined` if it doesn't find one. That is its purpose. It takes a predicate (a function that returns a boolean) *in order to know which item to return*. It wouldn't really be called "find" if you would give it a predicate and didn't find an item for you. You probably want [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which tests the predicate and tells you if at least one item matches it.

Comment: Also, did you [check what `isInRange` is in your first piece of code](https://jsbin.com/jupepiwazu/1/edit?js,console)? Why do you say it's *not* an array (since you contrast it with the second one where it is)?

Comment: @VLAZ So in both cases `.find()` returns the first item and since `[from, to]` inside an if-condition is truthful both checks work. The problem would be then, that inside my `.forEach()` I can't return anything. Right?

Comment: [Why does this forEach return undefined when using a return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7209794) | [Function with forEach returns undefined even with return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16392445) | [Short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641347)  | [What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34653612)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are correct in saying that `Array#find` returns an element of the array or `undefined`. Since you're calling it on `ranges` which is an array of arrays, you get an array back.

You can use the `Array#some` method instead, which returns a `boolean` if the condition is met on any item of the array:

```js
function scriptOfSample(a, scripts) {
    const codePoint = sample.codePointAt(0);

    if (codePoint == null) return undefined

    const system = scripts.find(
        (script) => script.ranges.some(
            ([from, to]) => from <= codePoint && codePoint <= to
        )
    );

    return system ? system.name : undefined
}
```