# v-if function returning nothing, but it should

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Running into an issue that's been bugging me for the past 2 hours.

I've got a function in a mixin like so:

```
 checkPermissionMeetings(type,areaID){
            if(this.$store.state.global.permissions.meetings===true) { //If user has basic meeting access
                if(type==='write'){
                    Object.entries(this.$store.state.global.permissions.meeting_areas).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                        if (parseInt(key) === parseInt(areaID) && (val === 'write')) {
                            console.log('write_true')
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }
                if(type==='read'){
                    Object.entries(this.$store.state.global.permissions.meeting_areas).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                        if (parseInt(key) === parseInt(areaID) && (val === 'read' || val === 'write')) {
                            console.log('read_true')
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
```

I am calling it in a view component which renders a navigation bar:

```
<span v-for="area in area_meetings">
                        {{area.id}} {{$store.state.global.permissions.meeting_areas[area.id]}} //This is here so I can see that I am sending the correct values to the function
                        {{checkPermissionMeetings('read', area.id)}} //This is here so I can see the output, but it returns nothing
                        <router-link tag="v-list-item" link :to="'/meetings/'+area.id" class="ml-5" v-if="checkPermissionMeetings('read', area.id)">
                            <v-list-item-icon>
                                <v-icon>mdi-chair-rolling</v-icon>
                            </v-list-item-icon>
                            <v-list-item-title>{{area.name}}</v-list-item-title>
                        </router-link>
                    </span>
```

I've console logged the outputs as you can see in the code, and they are looking ok. I have also put the function in curly braces so I can see the return, but this returns nothing at all.

[image: This is an image]

I can see them in my store

[image: This is an image]

I'm even echoing them out on the render and the values match...

[image: This is an image]

Is there something fundamental I'm missing here?

Comment: Try using `.some` instead of `.forEach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `return` into `forEach` method, your main function doesn't return anything. You can try to save in some variable returned data and after `if` statements return it. Or more easy way it use another loop like `for of`

Comment: Thank you, so obvious. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: @user3274489 Every programmer makes such obvious mistakes) I myself have had this many times

Answer (score 2):

As claimed in other answers, using `for`  would be working but I will describe why it won't work:

```js
function functionWithForEach(arr) {
arr.forEach(a=>{
    if(a == "matched"){
        return "horrah";
    }
})
// here it is anonymous function
//The return exits the current function which is anonymous so it doesn't get returned
}

function functionWithForOf(arr){
    for(let a of arr){
        if(a == "matched"){
            return "horrah";
            // here it is not anonymous function
        }
    }
}

function functionWithPlainFor(arr){
    for(let index =0; index < arr.length; index++){
        if(arr[index]=="matched"){
            return "horrah";
        }
    }
}

function functionWithForEachVariable(arr) {
    let wordMatched = "";
arr.forEach(a=>{
    if(a == "matched"){
        wordMatched = "horrah";
        return "horrah";
    }
}
)
// see how the return does let code below it to execute
console.log("I will be called no matter return is called inside forEach");
return wordMatched;
}



let matchingArr = ["mat","matched","not correct"];

console.log(functionWithForEach(matchingArr),"from forEach");
console.log(functionWithForOf(matchingArr),"from for-of");
console.log(functionWithPlainFor(matchingArr),"from plain for");
console.log(functionWithForEachVariable(matchingArr),"from forEach with Variable");
```

It is clear from these that we can't use forEach in this situation

If you wanna know more about these:

[What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function)

[Short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

[Why does this forEach return undefined when using a return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209794/why-does-this-foreach-return-undefined-when-using-a-return-statement)

Comment: Thanks for that info! I will read up :)